# where and orwhere is not working on eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

```
$classes = Classes::all();
if (!empty($request) and $request->search != null)
    $classes = $classes->where('class_name', 'like', '%' . $request->search . '%')
        ->orWhere('class_number', 'like', '%' . $request->search . '%');
```

Here both where and orWhere are not working in eloquent says Bad Method call. can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Since you retrieved `$classes` with `all()`, it is now a Collection, not a QueryBuilder object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$classes` is currently a Collection, not a QueryBuilder object. Add the full query to the if block and move the default to an else, like this:

```
if (!empty($request) and $request->search != null) {
    $classes = Classes::where('class_name', 'like', '%' . $request->search . '%')
        ->orWhere('class_number', 'like', '%' . $request->search . '%')
        ->get();
} else {
    $classes = Classes::all();
}
```